# How can i loadData function as part of the Ext.data.JsonStore ExtJS3.0.0?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I am running into with the loadData function as part of the Ext.data.JsonStore, Here data has come json format, but data didn ot load in jsonStore.

```
xtype: 'combo',
                    id: 'cmblocation',
                    width: 211,
                    displayField: 'name',
                    valueField: 'id',            
                    store: land,
                    emptyText: 'Select Location',
                    allowBlank: false,
                    listeners: {
                        afterrender: function () {
                            Ext.Ajax.request({
                                url: 'http://localhost:58316/Test.asmx/GetAll',
                                method: 'GET',
                                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                                success: function (response) {                               
                                  var data = Ext.decode(Ext.decode(response.responseText).d);                                                           
                                   land: new Ext.data.JsonStore({
                                        root: data,
                                        fields: ['Id', 'Name']                                 
                                    });
```

Comment: I would definitely recommend that you use `store.load` function. No need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to use [`loadData`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.JsonStore-method-loadData) method of [`JsonStore`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.JsonStore).

A **loadData** method Loads an array of data straight into the Store.

Using this method is great if the data is in the correct format already (e.g. it doesn't need to be processed by a reader). If your data requires processing to decode the data structure, use a [MemoryProxy](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Memory) or [loadRawData](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-loadRawData).

In this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2edo)**, I have created a demo using `combobox` and `Ext.Ajax.request`. I hope this will help/guide  you to achieve your requirements.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Demo',

    launch: function () {
        //Create combobox
        Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
            fieldLabel: 'Choose Country',
            queryMode: 'local',
            margin: 10,
            store: Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
                fields: ['code', 'name'],
                storeId: 'countryJsonStore'
            }),
            displayField: 'name',
            valueField: 'code',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            listeners: {
                afterrender: function (combo) {
                    //Call Ajax request to get data from json/server
                    Ext.Ajax.request({
                        //Here is server url/your method name
                        url: 'country.json',
                        method: 'GET',
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                        },
                        success: function (response) {
                            var data = Ext.decode(response.responseText).data;
                            /*
                             * Loads an array of data straight into the Store.
                             * Using this method is great if the data is in
                             * the correct format already (e.g. it doesn't need to be processed by a reader).
                             * If your data requires processing to decode the data structure, use a MemoryProxy or loadRawData.
                             */
                            combo.getStore().loadData(data);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

For ExtJS 3.0, you can refer this **[FIDDLE](http://rextester.com/VBFEM38106)**

**CODE SNIPPET Extjs 3.0**

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    // create the combo instance
    var combo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
        typeAhead: true,
        triggerAction: 'all',
        lazyRender: true,
        mode: 'local',
        store: new Ext.data.JsonStore({
            // store configs
            autoDestroy: true,
            storeId: 'myStore',
            fields: ['country_id', 'country_name']
        }),
        valueField: 'country_id',
        displayField: 'country_name',
        listeners: {
            afterrender: function(combo) {
                //Call Ajax request to get data from json/server
                Ext.getBody().mask('Please wait...');
                Ext.Ajax.request({
                    //Here is server url/your method name
                    url: 'http://vocab.nic.in/rest.php/country/json',
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        Ext.getBody().unmask();
                        var data = Ext.decode(response.responseText);

                        /*
                         * Loads an array of data straight into the Store.
                         * Using this method is great if the data is in
                         * the correct format already (e.g. it doesn't need to be processed by a reader).
                         * If your data requires processing to decode the data structure, use a MemoryProxy or loadRawData.
                         */
                        combo.getStore().loadData(data.countries.map(item => {
                            return item.country;
                        }));
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });

    combo.render(document.body);
});
```

> You can also use proxy inside of [jsonstore.](http://docs.huihoo.com/extjs/3.0.0/docs/source/JsonStore.html#cls-Ext.data.JsonStore)

You can see In this **[FIDDLE](http://rextester.com/XLGN34293)**

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.onReady(function() {

    var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        autoLoad: true,
        root: 'countries',
        url: 'http://vocab.nic.in/rest.php/country/json',
        fields: ['country', {
            name: 'code',
            type: 'string',
            convert: function(v, rec) {
                return rec.country.country_id;
            }
        }, {
            name: 'name',
            type: 'string',
            convert: function(v, rec) {
                return rec.country.country_name;
            }
        }]
    });

    // create the combo instance
    var combo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
        mode: 'local',
        store: store,
        valueField: 'code',
        displayField: 'name',
    });

    combo.render(document.body);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Narendra Jadhav for your answer ,i have follow your instruction but unfortunately it is not working.I am using extjs 3.0.0 version.

Comment: Ok @rajib86 please see I have updated my answer with ExtJS3.0. please refer this **[FIDDLE](http://rextester.com/VBFEM38106)**